# ASP.NET MVC3 not working in Windows 8

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, iis, razor

is there anything special I need to do to get ASP.NET MVC3 enabled on my Windows 8 Release Preview install? Creating even a blank ASP.Net MVC3 Razor application in VS2010, deploying to the local IIS instance as a new application, and loading the page in the browser doesn't work. I'm met with the following error:

HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden

The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

So I've then gone in to the new VS2010 project, right click, select "Add Deployable Dependencies" and selected "ASP.NET MVC" along with "ASP.NET Web Page with Razor syntax"
 Then I re-deploy the project to local IIS application. No change. Still "web server not configured to list contents of the directory".

It's worth noting the VS 2010 Development Web Server works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Found it. Turns out even though I'm using ASP.NET MVC3 and had the .Net 4.0 framework installed, the Windows 8 "feature" for ASP.NET 4.5 needed to be installed for all this to wire up. Seems a bit counter-intuitive, but changing that did it.

Comment: Great you found a solution that worked for you and thanks for posting back here! Please add your solution as an answer and accept it. This way everybody knows how you solved it.

Comment: It might be that the system does not allow you to do this right away, but after 48 hours you ca normally do this.

Comment: I have ASP.NET 4.5 installed on Windows 8, but I still get this error.  The Web Platform Installer for MVC 3 doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it. Turns out even though I'm using ASP.NET MVC3 and had the .Net 4.0 framework installed, the Windows 8 "feature" for ASP.NET 4.5 needed to be installed for all this to wire up. Seems a bit counter-intuitive, but changing that did it.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider running the MVC3 installer on your host machine so that all dependencies for MVC3 projects are stored in the GAC. If you need the install package you can download it from:

http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=MVC3

I can't verify that this works on the Windows 8 preview, but it would be my first instinct upon running into your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ensure that the worker process for the site is configured for .NET 4?

When you say you "Deployed", how did you do that?  It sounds like the folder is not being set to an application.

Answer (score 0):

For me .NET 3.5 was not installed for IIS 8 in Windows features. Although I'm pretty sure my app is .NET 4.0... Worth trying though.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems installing MVC3 MS VS 2010. Windows 8 x64. The platform installer shows no errors.
Root cause : aspnetwebpages.msi breaks updating `web.config` files. I updated two web.config files which appeared to only contain blanks.
Here are my directions:

Ensure `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\web.config` is valid. Use web.config.default, copy then rename to web.config to correct if it looks wrong.

Ensure `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\web.config` is valid.  Use `web.config.default`, copy then rename to `web.config` to correct if it looks wrong.

I don't know why the files were bad in the first place.